# C# AddFontResource does not work - returns 2 fonts installed when called on only 1 font

Tags: c#, fonts, pinvoke

I am trying to programmatically install a True-Type font in C# on Win7 64 bit.

For some reason, when I call AddFontResource, the font does not install correctly and I get a return of "2" even though I'm only adding one font.

The font installs correctly if I just double-click it and install it using the regular Windows font installing interface, so I know it's a proper font.  If I call AddFontResource on an invalid path, then I get the correct return of 0 for no fonts installed, so it seems like it's doing "something" and finding the font file, but whatever it's doing, it isn't working.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,  uint Msg, int wParam,  int lParam);
    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpFileName); 
    public static void InstallFonts()
    {
        const int WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x001D;
        const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
        int Ret = AddFontResource(@"C:\FontFile.ttf");
        int Res = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
    }
```

The font "FontFile.ttf" obviously exists.  As I mentioned, AddFontResource returns 2, which makes no sense, and SendMessage returns 1 so it's sending out correctly.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Thanks!